# Amcharts synchronize cursor on 2 charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I m using Amcharts with 2 charts

with this function, i want synchronize cursors **based on datetime** on the 2 charts:

```
function syncCursor(event) {
    for (x in charts) {
        var date = AmCharts.stringToDate(charts[x].dataProvider[event.index][charts[x].categoryField], charts[x].dataDateFormat);
        charts[x].chartCursor.showCursorAt(date);
   }
}
```

The problem is this function works only if the arrays have exactly the same date values in each array else it seems the cursor from the second chart move to the same index, see below:
[image: Screen capture for arrays with differences on dates]

and link [arrays with differences on dates](http://jsfiddle.net/PRQkG/10/) 
and link [arrays with same dates](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/PRQkG/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=PRQkG)

Answer (score 1):

**Works!**

i replace the function by :

```
function syncCursor(event) {
        for (x in charts) {
            if(x==1){
            var date = AmCharts.stringToDate(charts[x].dataProvider[event.index][charts[x].categoryField], charts[x].dataDateFormat);
        charts[0].chartCursor.showCursorAt(date);
            }
            if(x==0){
            var date = AmCharts.stringToDate(charts[x].dataProvider[event.index][charts[x].categoryField], charts[x].dataDateFormat);
            charts[1].chartCursor.showCursorAt(date);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how would you achieve this with Amcharts 4?